# Function to be executed only once per day

Tags: wordpress, cron

I have a function abc () in my functions.php. I want this function to be ONLY run once per day.

How can I make sure that is case?

I understood so far, that when I would use the hook 'init', it would schedule thousands of daily events. So how is it done correctly?

Greetings,

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for ist called a cron-job. You create a cron job like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_do_cron', [$this, 'doCron']);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_do_cron', [$this, 'doCron']);

/**
 * Ajax endpoint to be used as a cron url
 */
public function doCron()
{
    $key = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'key');

    if ($key === 'dhsfvjusdfvu3vrju3vjuvgf') {
        // Execute your function here
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'NOPE';
    }    
    wp_die();
}
```

The Cron Job Execution can the be defined to run in your web-hosters confiuguration or by a third party service like this one: https://cron-job.org/en/ Basically you have the define the function you want to run in your doCron() function. These can the be set to run on a daily basis in your web hosters settings. You can also first test the function by accessing your sites url like this: http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=do_cron&key=dhsfvjusdfvu3vrju3vjuvgf . For your own environment you should change the key to somehting random. My preferred method for this is the good old 'forehead vs keyboard' Method ;)